# Laravel: log in the database if the rule of a request ist not correct

Tags: laravel, request, rules

I would like to log in the database if the rule of a request ist not correct.

```
\Validator::extend( 'my_validator', function ( $attribute, $value, $parameters ) {
$result = \DB::table( 'table' )->where( 'field1', $value )->where( 'field2', 'Y' )->exists();
if ( !$result ) {
    // Log in database the value of request->field3, request->field4, ...
    $log = new Log();
    $log->date = Carbon::now();
    $log->field3 = $request->field3;  // <<= How can I access here the input request of the fromula?
    $log->field4 = $request->field4;  // <<= How can I access here the input request of the fromula?
    // ... 
    $status = $log->save();
}
return $result;
} );

$validationRules = [
   'field' => 'my_validator'
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get access to request fields you should use either the facade `\Request` or `\Input`. In this case you can get a value of any field vey easily with code `\Request::get('field1');`

Comment: Thank you for your help! Oh yes: $this->field